# struck on string length function in c++

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

im relatively new to c++ and i am not able to get on with this code 
i have tried all the methods that are available but still get the result wrong.
Is this because of the string taking the values from the console??

I have mentioned the code link below

http://ideone.com/LL5pdw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    cin>>s;

    int i,count=0;
    for(i=0;s[i]!=0;i++)
        count++;
    int size = strlen( s.c_str() );

    cout<<size<<endl;
    cout<<s.length()<<endl;
    cout<<s.size()<<endl;
    cout<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What results are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: @chris - I think this is a learning exercise

Comment: Also, `s[i] != 0` is not a good test for a `std::string`. (actually, that might be "ok", but still looks weird - [std::string::operator\[\]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/)

Comment: Using the loop is not safe. Indexing a `std::string` with an index `>= size()` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: reading in a string from the console using std::cin is not a very good idea, it will read up to the first space and ignore the rest. Use getline if you want to read in user input to a string.

Comment: May want to check this out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/ if you're reading in "hello hi" it will only read "hello" and stop at the site of a space.

Comment: @snurby77 Thanks that worked.i knew that the count is being done upto the first whitespace but didnt know what exactly was causing the error.